# How to create segemented slider button like microsoft outlook

Tags: flutter

My goal is to have a segmented slider button from Microsoft outlook android

[image: Microsoft Outlook Android segmented slider button]

Did anyone know some package to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create using these two slutions
1)Using the [CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl/CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl.html) widget.
2)using custom stateful widgets

1)Using the CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl widget

```
    class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  
  int segmentedControlGroupValue = 0;
  final Map<int, Widget> myTabs = const <int, Widget>{
    0: Text("Focused"),
    1: Text("Other")
  };
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
          groupValue: segmentedControlGroupValue,
          children: myTabs,
          thumbColor:Colors.blueAccent,
          onValueChanged: (i) {
            setState(() {
              segmentedControlGroupValue = int.parse(i.toString());
            });
          });
  }
}
```

2)Using custom stateful widgets

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _forcused = true;
  bool _other = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          color:Colors.grey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
        child: Row(children: [
          Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _forcused = true;
                      _other = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("Focused",style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))
                      ),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(_forcused
                        ? Colors.blueAccent
                        : Colors.grey)
                  )
              )),
          Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _other = true;
                      _forcused = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("Other",style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))
                      ),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(_other
                        ? Colors.blueAccent
                        : Colors.grey)
                  )
              )),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to checkout the [CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl-class.html) widget .